ceiling fan mounting help
I removed the old 15.5" box which has 2 2.5" wood screws diagonally run into the stud. As far as I can tell the box itself is not rated for 35 lbs (recommended for the fan).
I need to install a new 21" box that is rated for 50 lbs, but I have insulation in the ceiling and was hoping to get some ideas on how to securely mount the new box so that it supports the fan.
I'm guessing 2 diagonally run wood screws are not strong enough.

Do you have axcess to above the ceiling?

No unfortunately not.

Some pictures of the ceiling and what's above it would help.

At 50 pounds, I'd get a box that can attach to two studs. If 16" spacing, the 21" box should do.

There is insulation above the drywall between the studs in the ceiling. Space is limited to none.
